# Initializing a jquery mobile widget on a page gives "Cannot read property 'jQuery....' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/T7qvv/)

The site has 2 (or more) pages defined in HTML like this:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" id="page1-content">
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Next Page</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" id="page2-content">
        <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Go Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Javascript - I am at once initializing everything:

```
$(function(){
    $('#page1-content, #page2-content').each(function(){
        var ul = $('<ul>');
        $.each(['one','two','three'], function(item){
            ul.append('<li><a href="#">'+item+'</a></li>');
        });
        ul.appendTo(this).listview();
    });
});
```

But the page only initializes the list view on the 1st page, and the list view on the 2nd (and not currently visible) page does not initialize and gives me an error.

```
Cannot read property 'jQuery19107783124386332929' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

I really want to be able to start fetching the data and at least create the DOM in every page at once in the beginning, rather than waiting till the user clicks "Next Page".

Also - the list view on the first page is overlapping the "Next" button. I see this overlapping often and would like to fix/understand this too.

Comment: You can't call enhancement on a page which isn't created yet. If you remove #page2-content or visit that page and then call enhancement it will work.

Comment: @Omar I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "call enhancement" - I am new to jquery mobile, so I'm not familiar with that terminology. Also - when you say that the page "isn't created yet" - that seems confusing to me since the `<div>` for that page is in the HTML document. When does the page "get created" and what does that mean?

Comment: calling enhancement means creating/modifying widget manually i.e. `.listview()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page `data-role=page` in jQuery Mobile passes through different stages, as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

> **Image / diagram source**: http://bradbroulik.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html

Enhancing widgets manually should be called on active page only, otherwise it will result in a error.

To do add fresh elements on different pages, you need to do this when [`pagecreate`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/) or [`pagebeforecreate`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/) events occur, without the need to call any enhancement method. As the widget will be auto-initialized/enhanced during that stage.

Also, you have a mistake in your code where you didn't close `ul` tag. However, this didn't cause the error.

The below code shows how to add elements to different pages without the need to call any enhancement method manually.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role=page]", function (e) {
    var ul = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>'),
        html = '';
    $.each(['one', 'two', 'three'], function (item) {
        html += '<li><a href="#">' + item + '</a></li>';
    });
    ul.append(html);
    $('[data-role=content]', this).append(ul);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hTyzK/)**

Comment: I'm sorry to tack on one more thing to this question - But can you please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gnZC/ - In this case I want to add some `li` tags to the `ul` dynamically after some time (simulating ajax call). But I do not know if the #page2 was initialized or not - what is the easiest way to add those `li` and not throw an error? In this fiddle if you click next page right away you will see the issue.

Comment: @codefactor are you going to use setTimeout function, or is it just for demo?

Comment: The reason I added the setTimeout is to simulate what would happen if I started an AJAX call right as the page loaded - then when the ajax call comes back the data is available.

Comment: you could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5gnZC/1/ @codefactor

Comment: Thank you again for your help - I found something else that works too. What if I did this: `$('#myitems').closest('.ui-page').trigger('create')` always instead of doing an `if (...) { ..listview('refresh')` - The benefit I see with the create is I could create many widgets with the `data-role` when the AJAX comes back, and they would all enhance (without explicitly calling the enhancement function inside of the if statement. Or would that perhaps enhance out of sequence in the life-cycle, and would be bad for some reason?

Comment: @codefactor I just tried `create` and `pagecreate` but they didn't work. Note that those methods dont enhance all widgets, some widgets still needs calling enhancement. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5gnZC/2/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a particular issue of the versions combination you're using, but before checking that, I would try **delegating on the 'pageinit' event instead of the regular document ready**.

Please try this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    $('#page1-content, #page2-content').each(function(){
        var ul = $('<ul>');
        $.each(['one','two','three'], function(item){
            ul.append('<li><a href="#">'+item+'</a></li>');
        });
        ul.appendTo(this).listview();
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems it partially works, it gives some errors up front and the first page is not initialized properly. But when you go to the 2nd page you see it is fine there, and then go back to first page, the first page was initialized sometime after switching to the 2nd page.